# Minimum area of a square and a circle of total 1 unit circumference length

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, geometry, algebra-precalculus

We have a 1 unit line and we can can cut it into 2 parts, where 1 part is used at the circumference of the square and the other as the circumference of a circle. How do i find out where to cut the line to get the least area as possible?

Comment: What have you tried? Can you write an equation expressing the total area, if the line was cut at $x$?

Comment: cut up the wire and made x and 100-x as the cuts, then found A=A_s+A_c, derivated it and found 0,56 unit for the square, but how can i be sure that is correct?

Comment: Write it up (either in your question, or as an answer), and people can look it over.

Comment: FWIW $x \approx 0.56$ is indeed the minimum.

Comment: What? why edit it wrong? changed it now

Comment: My apologies and thanks @ AndersJensen   I went entirely  by intuition of single square/circle.maximization,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say the part of length $x$ forms the circle. That circle has radius $\frac x{2\pi}$ and area $\frac{x^2}{4\pi}$. The remaining part of length $1-x$ forms a square with side $\frac{1-x}4$ and area $\frac{(1-x)^2}{16}$. So we have to minimise
$$\frac{(x-1)^2}{16}+\frac{x^2}{4\pi}=\left(\frac1{16}+\frac1{4\pi}\right)x^2-\frac x8+\frac1{16}$$
and the minimum occurs where the derivative is zero:
$$\left(\frac18+\frac1{2\pi}\right)x-\frac18=0$$
$$x=\frac{1/8}{1/8+1/2\pi}=0.439900\dots$$
So this length is reserved for the circle, and the remaining part for the square.

Comment: This is what i did. Can this be used? $A=A_s+A_c$ such that $A(x)=(\frac{x}{4})^2+\pi(\frac{100-x}{2\pi})^2$, Then find the derivate:
$A'(x)=2(\frac{x}{4})\cdot\frac{1}{4}+2\pi(\frac{100-x^2}{2\pi})(\frac{-1}{2\pi})\Longrightarrow$ $0=\frac{8}{x}+\frac{x-100}{2\pi}$, $0=\pi x+4(x-100)$, $0=4x+ \pi x-400\Longrightarrow$ $x=\frac{400}{4+\pi}\approx56$

Comment: Yeah, i see that by looking at your solution!

Answer (score 2):

Let the square and circle parts be partitioned $ (x, 1-x)$ respectively.

$$ x= 4a,\, 2 \pi r = (1-x),\, U= 4 a + 2 \pi r $$

$$ A = a^2 + \pi r^2 $$

EDIT1:

simplifies to

$$ \frac{4 A}{\pi} = \frac{\pi x^2}{4}+(1-x)^2 = x^2(\pi/4+1)-2x+ 1 $$

By usual differentiation its parabola graph has at

$$ x=\frac{1}{1+\pi/4} \approx 0.44$$

gives a *minimum* for square/circle.

Also, by Lagrange Multiplier method we gain extra geometrical insight ( I mention this  even if outside pre-calculus scope ):

$$ U= 4a+2\pi r;\, A = a^2+\pi r^2;$$

If each of $U$ and $A$ are partially differentiated with respect to $r$ and $a$ separately, and their ratios equated, we get a simple relation

$$ a = 2r$$

or the side should equal the circle diameter   if laid side by side after dividing the given length of string as sketched below:

[image: Square and Circle]

Comment: $a^2=\frac{x^2}{16}$ not $\frac{x^2}{4}$

Comment: answer should be 0.44 and 0.56

Comment: Thanks @DanielMathias    and@ AndersJensen  Error is corrected.